# how can i check my token on very request

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

Here im using angularjs with webApi  when i login with my credentials its generating Token as

```
data:
access_token:"SKvWJ2-IK_Zohn6xLS6HXydoV1NdovM5wvtcTvJM0hkZ"
expires_in:86399
token_type:"bearer"
```

This Token is stored in

```
 LoginFac.LoginWithToken(obj).then(function (d) {
            sessionStorage.employee = angular.toJson(d);
```

I stored my authentication Details in `sessionStorage.employee`  when i need my `access_token` And `token_type` how can i get it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`sessionStorage.getItem`** and  **JSON.parse** and then access the property **`access_token`**

Comment: use session storage

Comment: sessionStorage .getItem its fetches all my credential but i need only access_token

Comment: just do sessionStorage .getItem().access_token

Comment: var accesstpeknId = sessionStorage.getItem('employee').access_token;   Its showing undefind

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage .getItem()))

Comment: then you use cookie!

Comment: Beware of storing tokens in storage that can be accessed from Javascript - especially long lived ones like this one - since any XSS vulnerability in your application, would leave you open to having the tokens stolen. I usually store tokens in a httpOnly cookie.